# Refresh bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have this bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="nuovoUtente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Aggiungi utente</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="formUtenti" action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="aggNomeUtente" placeholder="Inserisci il nome">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Cognome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="aggCognomeUtente" placeholder="Inserisci il cognome">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Funzione</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="aggFunzioneUtente" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-Mail</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="aggMailUtente" placeholder="Inserisci la Mail">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle warningTriangolo"></i> Credenziale di accesso</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="aggPasswordUtente" placeholder="Inserisci la Password">
                    <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle warningTriangolo"></i> Credenziale di accesso</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="aggNuovoUtente" class="btn btn-primary">Salva e invia</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="chiusuraAgg" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi senza salvare</button>
            </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a user click to the button is send to a js-page that make a jquery ajax for a php page...this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../PHP/getuser.php?az=nuovoUtente',
        data: utente,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false
    })
    .done(function(data){
  alert("Inserito");  
    })
    .fail(function(){
        $('.modal-body').html('Qualcosa è andato storto, prova di nuovo. Molto probabilmente esiste già un utente con le                tue credenziali');
    });
```

my problem is this:
If the user enters a mail or password that is already in the database (and in this case I end up in the method .fail) the modal loses its HTML formatting and fills it with the text I wrote in the .fail.
I want when I close the modal I go back to the initial formatting in HTML. How do I?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Psylene/y08hf582/17/) as a solution.

**Explanation:**
I would put both sections into the modal and hide the one that isn't necessary, and toggle in the error message when required.

Note that I have adjusted your existing `<div>` to have an `id` field such as

`<div class="modal-body" id="main">`

and the error message has been added into the code using

`<div id="errmsg" class="modal-body" style="display: none;">`

Comment: Great to hear this answer works for you. Please mark as the correct answer if it answers your question :)

Comment: To mark an answer as correct, click on the check mark / tick mark next to the answer to change it from grey to green [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) :)